# before_save not working with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this Project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :status, :inclusion => { :in => ['active', 'closed'] }
  validates :title,
            :presence => true,
            :length => { :in => 4..30 }

  before_save :set_default_status_if_not_specified

  private 

  def set_default_status_if_not_specified
    self.status = 'active' if self.status.blank?
  end
end
```

If I create a new object like this:

```
Project.create!(:title => 'Test 2', :pm_id => 1)
```

I get these errors: **Validation failed: Status is not included in the list**
But status field should get filled in before save.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's because it validates **before** `before_save`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

```
(-) save

(-) valid

(1) before_validation

(-) validate

(2) after_validation

(3) before_save

(4) before_create

(-) create

(5) after_create

(6) after_save

(7) after_commit
```

You could try `before_validation` ?

Comment: You're right. before_validation now works fine! This order has been kept the same from Rails2? I've used it so many times without problems!

Answer (score 2):

[It looks like](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) validation happen before the `before_save` callbacks. Perhaps you want to try `before_validation` instead?